# The definite article before dark, darkness, light

Tags: articles, definite-articles, uncountable-nouns, zero-article

Why is there a definite article before the words *darkness* and *light* in the sentence below:

> But as is so often true, the darkness lingers longer than the light.

And why is the expression *in the dark/darkness* usually followed by *the* but sometimes by no article (I can see in the darkness. / I saw someone climbing aboard in darkness.) Since the nouns are uncountable and not specified (in my examples) and *the* is not needed by the rules.

Comment: Light and darkness can appear both with or without the definite article. Where the article appears, it gives them a slightly more specific sense. *There was a power cut and in the darkness, I couldn't find the door*. It refers specifically to the darkness created by the power cut.  But if I say "Light is better than darkness for finding your way around* neither is referring to any particular light or darkness. But this is not a hard and fast rule. One can leave out the article in specific cases too.

Comment: But aren't the words in my first and second sentences referring to light and darkness in general?

Comment: @zhabometr - we don't know because you did not give enough context, but, because it says **the** darkness, we assume that it is a darkness that has been previously mentioned or a darkness of which the reader is aware. Thus it is more specific.

Comment: While endorsing @Greybeard's comment entirely, note that I did say that it is not a hard and fast rule. And you see exceptions both with and without article.

Comment: @Greybeard - I've checked out the context of the sentence and found out that the author explains doings meant by the light and the author later.